# Не видит аргумент функции в lobasic

Tags: libre-office

В lobasic при слздании функции в ее части написании кода не могу сослаться на аргумент. Аргумент не видин функцией. Почему?

код

Function printme(byval s as string) as string
Dim s as string 'и так не видит
Printme = s ' не видит
End function